# Coming up with a counter example - calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, examples-counterexamples

I have to come up with a counter example for the following statement:

Let $f$ be a function $f: [0,\infty)\longrightarrow R$, continuous and bounded. Prove that it receives either a minimum or a maximum (or both)

Everything I tried seems to always be lacking one of the conditions, for example $\sin(1/x)$ is not continuous at $0$, $x\sin(x)$ is unbounded, $\sin(x) + 1/x$ does have a minimum

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, I was sure I got it write, can you tell me what exactly is wrong with my math writing?

Comment: I corrected your math formatting.  Please take a look at the changes I made.

Comment: How do I compare both versions?

Comment: What about $(1-e^{-x})sin(x)$?

Comment: @natitati https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4879678/revisions .  I thought your math markup was adequate. I had no trouble understanding what you wrote.  I would not have complained about it.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that continuous functions on compact intervals achieve a min/max?

Comment: That seems not useful, since $[0,\infty)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways that a function can fail to achieve a maximum:

1. It can increase to $\infty$
2. It can approach the maximum, without quite reaching it, as $1-\frac1x$ increases toward $1$ without getting there

Since the function you are looking for is bounded, (1) is ruled out. It must be (2).

Similarly, if the function fails to achieve a minimum, it must approach its greatest lower bound closer and closer without getting there.

If the function approached one of its bounds and stayed close to that bound, the way $1-\frac 1x$ does, the function wouldn't get arbitrarily close to the *other* bound.  So it can't be monotonic.  It must wiggle back and forth between the two bounds, getting close to the upper bound, then close to the lower bound, then closer to the upper bound, then closer to the  lower bound.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, although I was able to already arrive at that conclusion myself. I understand that it should "wave" up and down, each wave being further than 0. I was just not sure how can I come up with the actual formula for such a function.

Comment: You said you considered $x\sin x$ already and recognized that it is not what you want. But consider the graph of $x\sin x$ and what it looks like.  It waves up and down, but the waves keep getting bigger.  Is there some other way you could modify the wave function of $\sin x$ so that instead of increasing to infinity the waves stay bounded?

Comment: I see where you're going to, but not sure how to modify the sin function so that it fits my needs like you said.

Comment: @natitati You have figured out that $\sin x$ takes care of the wiggling-back-and-forth part, so it just needs to be combined with something that approaches a finite bound asymptotically, unlike $x$. There are many ways to get a horizontal asymptote.

Answer (score 2):

You can take, for instance, $f(x)=\sin(x)\arctan(x)$. Its supremum and its infimum are $\pm\pi/2$, but none of them is reached. Besides, it is continuous and bounded (for each $x\in[0,\infty)$, $|f(x)|<\pi/2$).

Comment: That seems to work. I could say that it's bounded by $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$, but does never reaches them. Thanks.